# Applying all transformations not working even after saving

Tags: modeling, origin, transform-orientation

I am still new to blender. I am following a tutorial to build a scene and every time I open the file the objects keep moving to another location. I fix the objects and put them all into place then apply all transformations and save then I go to open the file and they are still in the incorrect positions.
All positions are set to 0 and scale to 1 when I apply the fixed transformation but the location doesn't save for some reason. I checked the transformation options and none of the boxes are checked under "affect only". Is there anything else I need to be doing?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your values are green, which means that you've created some keyframes on the Location, Rotation and Scale, that could explain your problem?

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! @moonboots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *Location, Rotation* and *Scale* values are green, which means that you've created some keyframes on them, open the *Timeline* window and delete these keyframes.